# Remove row from a file perl

Tags: perl, awk, sed

I have file with `|` delimited row in that i want to add check on the value of 8th position if the value matches i want to remove that row from the file and if it not matching i want to leave that in file.

Below is the file format , i want to remove all the rows which have `U` value on the 8th position

```
A|B|DADD|H|O| |123 A Street; Apt.2|U|M
A|B|DADD|H|O| |123 A Street; Apt.2|A|M
A|B|DADD|H|O| |123 A Street; Apt.2|B|M
A|B|DADD|H|O| |123 A Street; Apt.2|U|M
```

How we can do it this Perl or is there any way we can use Awk or Sed. But after removing i want to print  them as well .

I have tried sed but is matching through out the file i want to match at specific position.

```
sed -i '' "/$pattern/d" $file
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
perl -F'\|' -wlane'print if $F[7] ne "U"' file  > new
```

With `-a` switch each line is split into words, available in `@F` array. The separator to split on can be set with `-F` option (default is whitespace) and here it's `|`.  See [switches in perlrun](https://perldoc.perl.org/perlrun.html#Command-Switches). Then we just check for the 8th field and print.

In order to change the input file *in-place* add `-i` switch

```
perl -i -F'\|' -wlane'print if $F[7] ne "U"' file
```

or use `-i.bak` to keep (`.bak`) backup as well.

---

I see that a question popped up about logging those lines that aren't kept in the file.

One way is to hijack the `STDERR` stream for them

```
perl -i -F'\|' -wlane'$F[7] ne "U" ? print : print STDERR $_' file 2> excluded
```

where the file `excluded` gets the `STDERR` stream, redirected (in bash) using `2>`.  However, that can be outright dangerous since now possible warnings are hidden and corrupt the file intended for excluded lines (as they also go to that file).

So better collect those lines and print them at the end

```
perl -i -F'\|' -wlanE'
    $F[7] ne "U" ? print : push @exclude, $_; 
    END { say for @exclude }
' input > excluded
```

where file `excluded` gets all omitted (excluded) lines. (I switched `-e` to `-E` so to have `say`.)

Answer (score 1):

Sounds like this might be what you want:

```
$ cat file
A|B|DADD|H|O| |123 A Street; Apt.2|U|M
A|B|DADD|H|O| |123 A Street; Apt.2|A|M
A|B|DADD|H|O| |123 A Street; Apt.2|B|M
A|B|DADD|H|O| |123 A Street; Apt.2|U|M

$ awk -i inplace -F'[|]' '$8=="U"{print|"cat>&2"; next} 1' file
A|B|DADD|H|O| |123 A Street; Apt.2|U|M
A|B|DADD|H|O| |123 A Street; Apt.2|U|M

$ cat file
A|B|DADD|H|O| |123 A Street; Apt.2|A|M
A|B|DADD|H|O| |123 A Street; Apt.2|B|M
```

The above uses GNU awk for `-i inplace`. With other awks you'd just do:

```
awk -F'[|]' '$8=="U"{print|"cat>&2"; next} 1' file > tmp && mv tmp file
```

To log the deleted line to a file named `log1`:

```
awk -F'[|]' '$8=="U"{print >> "log1"; next} 1' file
```

To log it and print it to stderr:

```
awk -F'[|]' '$8=="U"{print|"tee -a log1 >&2"; next} 1' file
```

Comment: I want to log this removed line into a log file as well. How we can do this ?

Comment: Add `2>>the_log_file` to the end of the command line or change `print|"cat>&2"` to `print >> "the_log_file"`.

Comment: can't we store this a string variable using perl ?

Comment: How the heck would I know? I'm giving you an awk answer. Ask the guy providing the perl answer if you have a perl question.